# Restore the scroll position after close the overlay

Tags: overlay

In my case, I need to create a full page overlay, and when I close the overlay I'd like to see the scroll bar to stay at where it was. Exactly like what pinterest.com does.

But unfortunately, in my case, when I close the overlay, the scroll bar always sits on the top of the main page.

Does anyone have any idea about this?

Thanks